# Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desktop?

Tags: monitor

I want to know if its possible to use my laptop as a second screen. Both my laptop and desktop have Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: "Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desktop?" Yes. Could you provide more information about your system? The specifics of the layout? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot simply connect your laptop to your desktop as if it was a TV or desktop monitor, because laptops generally only provide video outputs but no video inputs.

One might be able to pull something like that off by using a complex setup of [Xdmx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdmx), [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) and probably some virtualisation/remote access software or protocols (e.g. [spice](http://www.spice-space.org/)) to get a virtual second screen on the desktop and to display it on the laptop (and access the laptop from your desktop via synergy). Of course this also comes with a huge computing overhead.

I don't know of any hardware solutions that would allow something like that, but I guess they would be almost as expensive as another desktop monitor.